Достать переменную из функции telebot python
Как достать переменные из функции telebot.
Имеется функция:
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Click', reply_markup=webAppKeyboard())

    username = message.from_user.username
    id=message.from_user.id
    user_name=message.from_user.first_name

Как достать переменные:

username, id, user_name

Чтобы использовать в другой функции.

А как вы хотите использовать/вызывать другую функцию?

Amgarak, я хочу эти переменные передать в другой скрипт через import скрипта и использовать их, чтобы сохранять в базу данных int переменную, которая будет принадлежать определенному телеграм аккаунту

ikikaidesu, по новой создавать эти переменные я не могу, так как хочу достать id пользовтеля и использовать его в другом скрипте, в котором написана логика веб приложения. когда я обьявляю переменные до функции, а позже в функции использую их, эти переменные почему-то подсвечиваются серым и считаются обьявленными внутри функции

В чём проблема сохранить значения в базу данных и потом к ним обращаться? Или можно просто вызвать "скрипт", скорее всего функцию, которая должна обрабатывать эти данные и передать аргументами их. Допустим def start(message): #тут вы делаете, что надо# new_func(id, message)

Если Вам просто нужно передать полученные значения переменных в другую функцию, то просто передайте их. Буквально. Пусть другая функция принимает аргументы и передайте в качестве параметров при вызове этой функции их.
def new_function(username, id, user_name):
    print(f'Обрабатываю данные: {username}, {id}, {user_name}')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Click', reply_markup=webAppKeyboard())

    username = message.from_user.username
    id=message.from_user.id
    user_name=message.from_user.first_name

    new_function(username, id, user_name)  # Вызвать другую функцию и передать ей эти переменные

Или возьмите какую-нибудь базу данных и сохраните туда эти данные, да даже в текстовый документ. А в другой функции, которую хотите для обработки этих данных использовать, просто возьмите данные из БД или файла.
